# iOS Navigation Bar not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my application I am trying to implement SideBar thru [AppCoda tut](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/). I added `RevealViewController`, `SideBarViewController` and and `NavigationController` in my app. Linked my main page i.e the initial View Controller `ChatViewController` with the NavContrl. ChatViewController - Is Initial View Controller is checked in storyboard, so that comes auto without any initialization.  Under NavigationController I can see "`Relationship "root view controller to Chats"`. In ChatViewController in `NavigationItem` I have added title and left button. If I change the color of NavBar in NavigationControlelr I can see the reflection in ChatViewController NavItem. This all tells, it is linked properly.

In ChatViewController.m, I have added :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

self.sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.100f green:0.100f blue:0.100f alpha:0.2f];    //colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];

//_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
//_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

}

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

//self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
// YES or NO makes no differ
```

While runtime, I don't see the NavBar, Title, left button anything. Their is just blank space on top of the view, but not even the color of NavBar or anything. Can anyone help me know what's wrong, why I am not able to see the NavigationBar.

I am stuck over here from yesterday. Can't find a solution for this problem. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE :- Storyboard Scrn shot
[image: Story board all 4 views]

Comment: R u used SWLRevalViewContoller and if its yes, plz show the screen shot of your Storyboard

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, yes I am using SWRevealViewController. I have added screen shot of my story board.

Comment: where will u call the current chat means swlrevalview controller sidebartableview cell clik event

Comment: ur coding is fine, u r not given the segue from sidebar to main VC

Comment: Right now the left button click - to call the Side bar event is in ChatViewController.

Comment: At this point I am not able to see the left bar only, so sidebar is not seen only any time. AS no left bar click to open the sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the `root controller` in `SWLRevalViewController`,just like[image]

bz your `Root Controller` is started in `SWLRevalViewController` not a `Chat View Controller` change this

this is the sample project for U, try this is the project link

https://www.sendspace.com/file/cte6n7

finally w want to delete the link of project use this

https://www.sendspace.com/delete/cte6n7/83ec66ba3781cc584068addc0aec11c6

Comment: I am not able to get what you are trying to tell me to do.

Comment: sry my english is poor, but I found error what the mistake u made,

Comment: if u don't mine canu send ur project karthik.saral@gmail.com, I solve your problem, if u believe me

Comment: Pls tell me I will do accordingly, as I have many views & will have to do the same with others also. So, please.

Comment: Don't worry bat poor english.

Comment: Do u mean that I should make my SWRevealViewController as Initial View Controller and not ChatViewController ?

Comment: ya correct, bz u were start the root view controller after the navigation controller, this is wrong in here

Comment: see the updated answer, this is resolve ur problem what the mistake u made, if u need any assitance, I am waiting for your reply,

Comment: Was seeing your project. Trying with my project.

Comment: Yes it did the work. On AppCoda site, they have not set the RevealVC as initial VC. They have set the MainVC as initial VC. Your trick did the job.

Comment: tanx for information, now it working, if yes, then up vote my answer, have a happy day friend

Comment: Now, I can't see the table contents of the Menu. Can you tell anything. I have already up voted your answer. Will mark as answer also. Pls help with the table visibility.

Comment: Oh I have not declared it in .m file. So.

Comment: Ok, 1 last Q. I have 5 items in the table & I want the last item to be on bottom of the view. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: use 2 tableview and 2 array and finally use if else condition, this is my choice

Comment: @Tvd, tanx a lot frnd, have a happy day

Answer (score 0):

ran into same problem, though late but solution found.

Just embed each, into each of the destination view controllers, a navigation controller. A **navigation bar** is bound to be **hidden** if view controller is **not** a child of a **Navigation Controller**.